# textFieldDidBeginEditing not fired at first tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

When i tap the textfield textFieldDidBeginEditing starts to be fired after second tap. When I remove below code and after inside the textFieldDidBeginEditing method. It is fired at first tap. How can I make it fired at first tap?

> [numKeyboard.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,
>   self.view.frame.size.height-numKeyboard.view.frame.size.height, 320,
>   320)];

.m file:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "HastaDAO.h"
#import "YatanHastaBilgileriDAO.h"
#import "SettingViewController.h"
#import "Global.h"
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
#import "AlerjiModel.h"
#import "AlerjiDAO.h"
#import "NumKeyboard.h"
@interface MainViewController ()
{
    int whichbtn;
}
@end
@implementation MainViewController
@synthesize player=_player;
@synthesize resultText1, resultText2,result,closeResult;
NSMutableArray *favTani;
HastaModel *yatanHastaBilgisi;
NSString *currentKey,*sound;
NSString *currentStringValue;
HastaModel *hasta;
int compareResult;
NSString *string=@"";
NSInteger didCompare=1;
UIImage *img;
NSString *str1,*str2;
NSInteger fromHistory=0;
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    if(fromHistory){

        self.resultText1.text=str1;
        self.resultText2.text=str2;
    }
}
+(void)set_from_view:(NSInteger)history scanner:(NSInteger)scanner{
    fromHistory=history;
}
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

        if (textField == self.resultText2 && (![self.resultText1.text isEqualToString:@""] && ![self.resultText2.text isEqualToString:@""])){
            [self destroyNumKeyboard];
            [self compareTwoBarcode];

        }


}
+(void)setResultTexts:(NSString*)str img:(UIImage*)image{
    string=str;
    img=[[UIImage alloc]init];
    img=image;
}

-(void)compareTwoBarcode{
    [self.resultText1 resignFirstResponder];
    [self.resultText2 resignFirstResponder];
    if(![self.resultText1.text isEqualToString:@""] && ![self.resultText2.text isEqualToString:@""] )
    {
        didCompare=1;
        if ([resultText1.text isEqualToString:resultText2.text]) {
            sound=@"%@/accept.mp3";
            result.text = @"EŞLEŞİYOR";
            result.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:153/255.0 green:255/255.0 blue:51/255.0 alpha:0.85];
            compareResult=1;
        }
        else
        {
            sound=@"%@/reject.mp3";
            result.text = @"EŞLEŞMİYOR";
            result.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:0/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:0.85];
            compareResult=0;
        }

        [closeResult setHidden:FALSE];
        [result setHidden:FALSE];

        NSString *soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:sound, [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
        NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
        player.numberOfLoops = 1; //Infinite

        if([SettingViewController getVolume])
            [player play];

        if([SettingViewController getVibrate]){
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
        }
    }else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Uyarı"
                                                        message:@"Barkod alanları dolu olmalıdır!"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Tamam"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

}
-(void)setHistorySource{
    NSString *word= self.resultText1.text;
    NSString *pathhistory = [[self documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"history.plist"];
    NSMutableArray *histList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathhistory];
    NSInteger ishist=0;
    for (NSInteger i=[histList count]-1; i>=0;i--) {
        NSDictionary *d = [histList objectAtIndex:i];
        //NSString *patientName=[d objectForKey:@"PATIENT"];
        NSString *name1=[d objectForKey:@"WORD1"];
        NSString *name2=[d objectForKey:@"WORD2"];
        if([name1 isEqualToString:self.resultText1.text] &&
           [name2 isEqualToString:self.resultText2.text])
            ishist=1;
    }

    if(ishist==0){
        HastaModel*hmodel=[[HastaModel alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray *arr=[HastaDAO getHasta:[self.resultText1.text intValue] yatanAyaktan:1];
        if([arr count]==0)
            arr=[HastaDAO getHasta:[self.resultText1.text intValue] yatanAyaktan:0];
        if([arr count]){
            hmodel=[arr objectAtIndex:0];
            NSDictionary *dic=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               hmodel.Ad, @"PATIENT",
                               self.resultText1.text, @"WORD1",
                               self.resultText2.text,@"WORD2",
                               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)compareResult ],@"EQUAL",
                               nil];
            [histList addObject:dic];
            if(![word isEqual:@""])
                [histList writeToFile:pathhistory atomically:TRUE];
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation{
    return(YES);
}
+(void)setbarcode1:(NSString*)barcode1 barcode2:(NSString*)barcode2{
    str1=barcode1;
    str2=barcode2;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.resultText1 setDelegate:self];
    [self.resultText2 setDelegate:self];

}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return true;
}

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    //if(textField==self.resultText2 && !resultText2.isFirstResponder){
    UIView *dummyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
    textField.inputView = dummyView;


    int i=0;
    for(UIViewController *vc in self.childViewControllers)
        if([vc isKindOfClass:[NumKeyboard class]])
        {
            i++;
            break;
        }
    if(!i){
        NumKeyboard* numKeyboard = [[NumKeyboard alloc] initWithNibName:@"NumKeyboard" bundle:nil];

        [numKeyboard.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-numKeyboard.view.frame.size.height, 320, 320)];
        [self.view addSubview:numKeyboard.view];
        [self addChildViewController:numKeyboard];
    }
    [self.view reloadInputViews];
    //}
}

-(void)destroyNumKeyboard {

    for(UIViewController *vc in self.childViewControllers){
                if([vc isKindOfClass:[NumKeyboard class]])
                {
                    [vc willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
                    [vc.view removeFromSuperview];
                    [vc removeFromParentViewController];
                    [self.parentViewController reloadInputViews];
                }

            break;
        }

    /*for (NumKeyboard *numKeyboardView in self.childViewControllers) {
        if(numKeyboardView){
            //UIButton son obje olduğu için
            //[self.view.subviews.lastObject removeFromSuperview];
            for (UIButton * btn in self.view.subviews) {
                if([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
                    if([btn.titleLabel.text  isEqualToString:@"X"]){
                        [btn removeFromSuperview];
                        break;
                    }
            }
            [numKeyboardView willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
            [numKeyboardView.view removeFromSuperview];
            [numKeyboardView removeFromParentViewController];
            [self reloadInputViews];
            break;
        }

    }*/

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(void) closeHastaDetail{
    [self.hastadetailview setHidden:TRUE];
}
-(void) closeHastaDetailDetail{
    [self.hastadetailindetailview setHidden:TRUE];
}
-(void) openHastaDetailDetail{
    [self.hastadetailindetailview setHidden:FALSE];
}
/*
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(textField.tag==2){
        NSCharacterSet* numberCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
        for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; ++i)
        {
            unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
            if (![numberCharSet characterIsMember:c])
            {
                return NO;
            }
        }

    }
    return YES;
}*/

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    currentKey=elementName;
    currentStringValue=nil;

}
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{
    if(tabBar.tag == 0)
    {
        [self closeHastaDetail];
        [self closeHastaDetailDetail];
    }
}

- (NSString *)documentsDirectory {
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}
+(void)setDidCompareZero{
    didCompare=0;
}

- (IBAction)closehastadetail:(id)sender {

    [self.hastadetailview setHidden:TRUE];

    [self performSelector:@selector(setHistorySource) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];
}
- (IBAction)push_CompareBtn:(id)sender {
    [self compareTwoBarcode];
}
- (IBAction) closeResult:(id)sender{
    [closeResult setHidden:TRUE];
    [result setHidden:YES];

    if([SettingViewController getTekliCokluArama]==1){

    }
}
- (IBAction)del_txt1:(id)sender {
    self.resultText1.text=@"";
}
- (IBAction)del_txt2:(id)sender {
    self.resultText2.text=@"";
}

- (IBAction) deleteResult:(id)sender{
    //[resultImage1 setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"]];
    resultText1.text = @"";
    //[resultImage2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"]];
    resultText2.text = @"";
}
- (IBAction) okDetailBtn:(id)sender{
    [self.hastadetailindetailview setHidden:TRUE];
}

- (IBAction) showDetail:(id)sender{
    [MainViewController set_from_view:0 scanner:0];
    [self openHastaDetailDetail];
}

- (IBAction)setHastaDetail:(id)sender {
    [self closeHastaDetailDetail];
    self.hastadetailview.contentSize =CGSizeMake(320, 600);
    [self.hastadetailview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.hastadetailview.contentOffset.x, 0)
                             animated:YES];
    if(hasta==nil)
        hasta=[[HastaModel alloc]init];

    if([self.resultText1.text length]>0){
        NSMutableArray *arr=[HastaDAO getHasta:[self.resultText1.text intValue] yatanAyaktan:1];

        if(![arr count] && ![self.resultText1.text isEqualToString:self.hastaProtokol.text])
            arr=[HastaDAO getHasta:[self.resultText1.text intValue] yatanAyaktan:0];

        if([arr count])
        {
            hasta =[arr objectAtIndex:0];

            if(![self.resultText1.text isEqualToString:self.hastaProtokol.text])
            yatanHastaBilgisi=[YatanHastaBilgileriDAO yatanHastaBilgileri:hasta.Id];

            self.hastaAd.text=hasta.Ad;
            self.hastaAd.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;
            self.hastaAd.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
            self.hastaProtokol.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)hasta.Id];
            self.hastaBolum.text=hasta.Bolum;
            self.hastaOda.text=hasta.Oda;
            self.hastaCinsiyet.text=hasta.Cinsiyet;

            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
            NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:yatanHastaBilgisi.DogumTarihi];

            self.hastaDogumTarihi.text=strDate;
            self.hastaYatak.text=hasta.Yatak;
            self.hastaDoktor.text=yatanHastaBilgisi.Doktor;

            if(hasta.LastOrderId>0)
            {
                NSMutableArray *arr1= [AlerjiDAO alerji:0 orderId:hasta.LastOrderId];
                NSString*hAlerji=@"";

                for(AlerjiModel *item in arr1 )
                {
                 if(![hAlerji isEqualToString:@""])
                     hAlerji=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",hAlerji,item.Ad];
                 else
                     hAlerji=item.Ad;

                }
                self.hastaAlerji.text = hAlerji;
            }else
                self.hastaAlerji.text =@"";

            [self.hastadetailview setHidden:FALSE];
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                            message:@"Hasta bulunamadı."
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Tamam"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
}@end
```

Comment: Can you show some code where the UITextField you are using is being created?

Comment: I created it in storyboard.

Comment: Hello, Please change the height of numKeyboard and then try.

Comment: But why should I change it? The y origin depends on the textfield's origin. :/

Comment: i think textFieldShouldBeginEditing will called first

Comment: I tried that but that method doesn't get called also.

Comment: Check Delegate of textfield means your binding reference of UITextField delegates to ViewController.. if you binding is already then remove and again bind it

Comment: @TheMall I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: make sure you write this `<UITextFieldDelegate>` in .h file like this `@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>`

Comment: I did that and recreate the objects again but it keeps behave same.

Comment: can you provide whole code means whole methods and implementation of .m file ?

Comment: I post the all things of m file. Sorry for late answer.